# How can I remove different lines of JSON file with the same pattern?

Tags: json, bash

Hi I have a json file with `5000` lines, part of a lot of lines follow the same pattern like this:

```
[
{"a":"c", "b":"e", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"/", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"/", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"e/esa", "i":"a"},
{"a":"i", "b":"a/e/", "i":"ah"},
]
```

And I want remove all lines with `"b":"/"` and I want this final file:

```
[
{"a":"c", "b":"e", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"e/esa", "i":"a"},
{"a":"i", "b":"a/e/", "i":"ah"},
]
```

How can I do it in Bash? Thanks.

Comment: If that's really what your file looks like, I don't think it's JSON.

Comment: You ask for a solution "in Bash". Do you mean using only bash builtins, or can the solution invoke external programs?

Comment: Only bash commands, sed, awk...

Comment: `grep -v 'b:/' file.txt > newfile.txt`

Comment: @JoanTriay - which is it? "Only bash commands" or can the solution invoke sed, awk, and other external commands?

Comment: I have to do it with the command line.

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: yes @MarcBit works for me

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using `sed`:

```
$ sed -i '/ b:\/,/'d x.j
```

Comment: Like so: `$ sed -i '/ "b":"\/",/'d x.j`

Answer (score 0):

**edit** in order to answer the updated question:

use sed:

```
$ cat testfile 
[
{"a":"c", "b":"e", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"/", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"/", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"e/esa", "i":"a"},
{"a":"i", "b":"a/e/", "i":"ah"},
]
$ sed -i '/"b":"\/",/d' testfile
$ cat testfile 
[
{"a":"c", "b":"e", "i":"a"},
{"a":"c", "b":"e/esa", "i":"a"},
{"a":"i", "b":"a/e/", "i":"ah"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

@marc-b Soultion it works very well, thanks!

```
grep -v 'b:/' file.txt > newfile.txt
```